# Target data values are not evenly distributed

Tags: python, logistic-regression, accuracy

Data nature:

I have features with 10 numeric type, and other 10 categorical, with a lot of  values, at the end, using one-hot encoding I got a matrix of 600 columns. My problem is with accuracy which is 0.7, knowing that other peers got more that 0.9.

Problem:

Target data is binary, and is not evenly distributed at all. Trying blindly after pre-processing `from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression` and `sklearn.svm` scored using `roc_auc_score`:  `.7` and `.75`.

Back to basics, I run this

```
train['cible'].value_counts() / train['cible'].count()
```

and got

```
1    0.970791
0    0.029209
Name: cible, dtype: float64
```

Quite interesting I think, but how can I improve accuracy. Any hints ?

Note: I will edit and add False Positive Rate and True Positive Rate as I lost output, after scaling, missing data imputation and retraining the model which takes couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `scikitlearn LogisticRegression` docs:

> **class_weight** : dict or ‘balanced’, default: None
>
> Weights associated with classes in the form {class_label: weight}. If
>   not given, all classes are supposed to have weight one. The “balanced”
>   mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely
>   proportional to class frequencies in the input data as n_samples /
>   (n_classes * np.bincount(y)). Note that these weights will be
>   multiplied with sample_weight (passed through the fit method) if
>   sample_weight is specified. New in version 0.17:
>   class_weight=’balanced’

So try to add `class_weight='balanced'`in your call to `LogisticRegression()`

Or maybe if this doesn't work, try to use as trainSet an evenly split dataset: where the number of samples of class 1 is equal to class 0.

Comment: I will give it a try and be back

Comment: From 0.75 to 0.8 ! No guess this helped in my case.